# Replace dash (-) in number array in javascript and make them into string array

Tags: arrays, numbers

i wanna make this aarray

let number = [022-123-456-2322,
021-123-456-2322,
031-123-456-2377,
041-123-456-2322,
];

to this

let number = [0221234562322,
0211234562322,
0311234562377,
0411234562322,
];

and make them to string array

let number = ["0221234562322,
0211234562322,
0311234562377,
0411234562322"
];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your first array has to already be an array of strings otherwise you get an array as [ -2883, -2884, -2931, -2868 ] because something like
041-123-456-2322 is not a valid instance of type number !

So you would have :

```
let number = ["022-123-456-2322", "021-123-456-2322", "031-123-456-2377", "041-123-456-2322"]
```

You can map over the number array with the following...

```
number = number.map(a => a.split("-").join(""))
```

... to get your array of :

```
number = ["0221234562322", "0211234562322", "0311234562377", "0411234562322" ]
```

Comment: oh i see, so the first array is already invalid from the begining right, i must manipulate the array manualy to this ["022-123-456-2322", "021-123-456-2322", "031-123-456-2377", "041-123-456-2322"],

thanks, i will tray it first

Comment: If my answer was helpful it would be nice to check the "correct answer" sign below the arrows.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

i already give a feedback (upvote), but here the note

Comment: Below the arrows is also a check sign for a right answer, that you can already click.

Comment: oh i see, already, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with this already.
Your first array is not possible, as if you console.log it, it actually is:

```js
let number = [-2883, -2884, -2931, -2868]
```

You need the first array to contain those numbers in string form, not as integers. This must be done in the code you already have. After that's done, then you can remove the '-' symbols from the strings, using .replace() or something similar.

Comment: thanks dude, i will manipulte the array forst